# why isn't this javascript fade in working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

not sure what's wrong here but just trying to do a simple fade in upon the page loading.

script in the head tag:

```
<script>
$("#header").delay(100).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url(door.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick tip: Always put your scripts just before `</body>` tag. In the `<head>` section just include libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your code in [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#header").delay(100).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
});
```

---

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: 4 times the same answer with only 12 seconds between first and last. :D +1 to this one for providing a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the script to a dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("#header").delay(100).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it when DOM is ready.
Write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#header").delay(100).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
});
```